# How to Select Tutorial Chapters in Uemacs

Tags: emacs

I finished installing uemacs 4.0.15.1 from github. I have some experience with GNU-emacs and I wanted to give this a try. I got stuck from the beginning. I opened (by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd>) the uEmacs/PK 4.0 HELP and saw at the bottom of the window

> Select topic from list and press < Help >.

There's no way I can select the topic from the list, at least no way I'm aware of. I use Terminal 0.4.4 on Xfce, Slackware. If someone could shed light on this...